# iPhone app got rejected: it provides to the user potentially inaccurate diagnostic functionality for iPhone OS devices

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

We've reviewed XXX and determined that we cannot post this version of your iPhone application to the App Store because it provides to the user potentially inaccurate diagnostic functionality for iPhone OS devices.  There is currently no publicly available infrastructure to support diagnostic analysis.  This may result in your app reporting potentially inaccurate information which could lead to user confusion.

Has anyone encountered this rejection reason? Can I just add the disclaimer in the app in order to get approved? Has anyone tried this? Or any other trick?

Comment: I hope this isn't another cellphone tracker app.. Just curious, but why *would* you show inaccurate diagnostic info as part of your app?  As a joke?

Comment: It would be helpful for us to know exactly what your application is doing for us to help provide a recommendation

Comment: Testing for screen dead pixels.

Comment: Apple might hold their ground on that one.  I've pushed back in the past when it was a misunderstanding, but more typically they just stop responding.  You could always add a disclaimer and see.

Comment: I'm curious, why test for dead pixels? If you can see them you don't need a test, if you can't see them why test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that it is impossible for an app to actually test for dead pixels, I'm going to say Apple is on solid ground here. Any such test would rely on a human actively observing the pixels so it wouldn't be an actual measurable diagnostic.

The situation with the App Store isn't like the situation with software that isn't sold through Apple. Given that Apple test and approves apps for basic functionality before allowing them in the App Store, letting through an App that claims to provide diagnostic information about hardware is tantamount to Apple stating that app does provide hardware diagnostic information.  However, the API does not provide such information and Apple is not going to hinge their warranty payouts on some, for example, 16 year old kid's idea of what makes an accurate diagnostic tool.

Apple is imagining this conversation:

> "Hello Apple? I have dead pixels on
>   my device. How do I know? I ran an app
>   that says I do. Hey! You approved the
>   app for the App Store so that's just
>   like saying it does detect dead
>   pixels! If it didn't you shouldn't
>   have accepted it!"

... and Apple's lawyer gets a new Porsch.

I ran into issues with 3rd party diagnostic software back when I was at Apple. One of the big headaches is that the 3rd party diagnostics offered no protection against false positives. Customers and Apple would spend a lot of money chasing false positives and the diagnostic provider would just shrug. It wasn't their problem and it didn't cost them any money.

Official diagnostic software has to be rigorously tested as false positives cost everyone a lot of time and money. Apple is not going to make a 3rd party tool quasi-official by adding it to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a "dead pixel" remedy. I remember the old PSPs used to have a quick color flash that fixed pixels well. Red, yellow, etc. Seizure status.

The probability of SEEING a dead pixel on the retina display is probably going to be very difficult if not impossible by the naked eye.